# Opening a file then closing does not release file lock

Tags: c++, linux, node.js

I have some c++ code in a node.js function that opens a file like this and reads it into a buffer and then closes it.

```
ifstream inputFile(source.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
inputFile.read(buffer, results.st_size);
inputFile.close();
```

Then I manipulate the file in some way and attempt to write it back to the same location. I get the following error code and message: "Text file busy". I know there is no other process touching the file. If I rename the file to some random name, and rename it back, then I am able to overwrite the file.

Comment: what platform are you using? When you say rename and rename it back is this before, during, or after execution of the program? Its sounds like its a platform dependent issue.

Comment: The rename takes place just before we attempt to write to the file. But again, the rename is the only thing that allows me to successfully open the file for writing. I'm not too familiar with linux, so this is my guess as to what the system is: GNOSE 2.28.2. Also the storage is a shared windows drive. This storage used to be hosted on Windows Server 2003 and it worked fine. When we switched to 2008 it stopped working. So clearly there is some environmental issue.